# Email sending isn't working on Google App Engine though no errors in logs

Tags: java, email, google-app-engine, html-email

[I have looked at all the questions related to this topic on SO but neither of them seems to explain the behaviour I am seeing].

I have two projects A (3-4 months old) and B (0.5 month old) and both use a common class to send email on Google App Engine. Both projects are currently running in the free quota.

When I invoke the common `Emailer` class from Project A, the email gets sent; invoking from B does not produce any errors in the log file (the logs show correct information in email fields), but the email never arrives at the recipient address. I have checked Spam folder/label and even searched entire mailbox for mail `from:appspotmail.com` (see below) and nothing.

I have verified that for each email sent, the email quota on Developer Console (at console.cloud.google.com/appengine/quotadetails?project=**project-b**&moduleId=default) registers another recipient, so obviously Google code is being invoked correctly (the email in question is for the reset password, so has only recipient).

I tried sending as `admin@mydomain.com` (`admin@mydomain.com` has been added to list of *Email API authorized senders* on the settings page of app B) and also as `admin@project-b.appspotmail.com` and neither one works.

On project A so far I have always sent email as `admin@project-a.appspotmail.com` (where `project-a` is the  id of my GAE app) and have never faced any issue of this sort.

What is going on here? Is there some additional setting I am missing out on?

**NB:** This probably doesn't have any bearing, but mentioning in the interests of completeness: the recipient email address is of the form `myaccount+xyz@gmail.com` instead of the more common `myaccount@gmail.com`. However, manually sending email to this address from within Gmail works, so that shouldn't be an issue.

#### Update 1

Based on suggestions here and things that I've tried since posting this question, here are some updates:

- I set up an email bounce handler as suggested but it hasn't been invoked yet (as per the logs).

  Maybe it'll be invoked after waiting 24-48 hours. Let's see.
- Set up account with email `simplename@gmail.com` and exactly the same thing (i.e., nothing) happened when I invoked *Forgot password* functionality.
- Changed sender email to `admin@project-name.appspotmail.com` (instead of `project-id`) and got an Unauthorized sender message in an exception.

  This means that the other addresses I have tried **have been authorized senders** as I never saw this exception with them.

Comment: did you configure your app to receive your bounced emails? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/bounce

Comment: just for completeness: what happens if you try to send emails to accounts that do NOT have the `myaccount+xyz@gmail.com` form?

Comment: @marianosimone I created an account for simplename@gmail.com and invoked _Forgot password_ functionality for that. It made no difference.

Comment: can you check if the msg body contains a link (to the app's `appspot.com` domain)?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to troubleshoot App Engine Email delivery problems is to [Configure Email Bounce Notification](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/bounce). As Emails are delivered asynchronously, any delivery problems will result in a bounce to the specified sender.

Comment: This hasn't yielded anything. Have not noticed anything in the logs. It seems the emails aren't bouncing, but aren't being delivered either...